# How can I properly set up a C library (nappgui) and integrate it with CMakeLists?

Tags: c, cmake

I'm totally confused, as I've tried setting up a graphics library called "nappgui". I've already set it up where it's all in the include and libs folders. I'm running into *so many* compiler errors.

Here's my `main.c`

```c
#include "nappgui.h"

typedef struct _app_t App;
struct _app_t
{
    Window *window;
};

static App *i_create(void)
{
    App *app = heap_new0(App);
    return app;
}

static void i_destroy(App **app)
{
    heap_delete(app, App);
}

#include "osmain.h"
osmain(i_create, i_destroy, "", App)
```

This was copied off of nappgui's [hello world step 2 example](https://nappgui.com/en/start/hello.html)

Here's my CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.22.1)


# Setup Include Directories
set(SOURCES src/main.c)
link_directories(libs)
include_directories(include)

# Setup Project
project(PALOMGR VERSION 0.1) # PALOMGR Short for "PulseAudio LOopback Manager"

# Setup Executable
add_executable(PALOMGR ${SOURCES})

# Link stuff up
target_link_libraries(PALOMGR PRIVATE -Llibs)

# Link EVERY SINGLE INCLUDE DIRECTORY
target_include_directories(PALOMGR PRIVATE include/osapp)
target_include_directories(PALOMGR PRIVATE include/core)
target_include_directories(PALOMGR PRIVATE include/draw2d)
target_include_directories(PALOMGR PRIVATE include/gui)
target_include_directories(PALOMGR PRIVATE include/geom2d)
target_include_directories(PALOMGR PRIVATE include/osbs)
target_include_directories(PALOMGR PRIVATE include/sewer)

target_compile_definitions(PALOMGR PRIVATE
    $<$<STREQUAL:${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE},Debug>:__DEBUG__ __ASSERTS__ __MEMORY_AUDITOR__>
    $<$<STREQUAL:${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE},Release>:__RELEASE__>
    $<$<STREQUAL:${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE},RelWithDebInfo>:__RELEASE__ __ASSERTS__ __MEMORY_AUDITOR__>
)
```

The command I'm using to publish and build everything

```bash
rm -rf build && mkdir -p build && cd build && cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug .. && make
```

What I'm hoping would have happened at this point was that it would go along and compile a simple app for me.

Here's the first of my problems:

```
include/sewer/config.hxx:36:6: error: #error Unknown Configuration
   36 |     #error Unknown Configuration
```

Here, it's showing that I've got an odd configuration, but the `config.hxx` file (in the relevant bit) shows this:

```
#if defined(CMAKE_DEBUG)
    #define __DEBUG__
    #define __ASSERTS__
    #define __MEMORY_AUDITOR__

#elif defined(CMAKE_RELEASE)
    #define __RELEASE__

#elif defined(CMAKE_RELEASEWITHASSERT)
    #define __RELEASE__
    #define __ASSERTS__
    #define __MEMORY_AUDITOR__

#else
    #error Unknown Configuration

#endif
```

Removing this whole section throws compiler errors everywhere.

I have to note that all the errors are happening during the execution of `make`, *not* `cmake`.

***HOW*** do I set this up properly?

Comment: what happens if you replace `cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug ..` with `cmake -DCMAKE_DEBUG ..` ?

Comment: "HOW do I set this up properly?" - Just follow the [guide](https://nappgui.com/en/guide/build.html). Its `CMakeLists.txt` includes script `CMakeNAppGUI.cmake`, which provides many helper functions for create applications and other things. If you want to write `CMakeLists.txt` without using those helpers, then you need at least to add those compile definitions, which are emitted with helpers. E.g.  the part of `config.hxx` you show definitely expects one of `CMAKE_DEBUG`, `CMAKE_RELEASE` and `CMAKE_RELEASEWITHASSERT` **macros** to be defined.